# Integration that look like incomplete Gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I am trying to solve the following integration $$\int_0^cx^{-k}e^{-gx^2}dx$$ where $c,k$ and $g$ are positive values. I know how to solve it if there were $k$ instead of $-k$. I need help with this integration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change of variable: $u=gx^2$ converts this integral to something like $$\alpha \int_0^\beta u^{-\lambda}e^{-u}du$$

Comment: @polfosol I agree with you completely but is there a way to go forward. I mean is there any general formula that solve the integral in your comment after this. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$I=\int x^{-k}e^{-gx^2}dx$$ change variable $$g x^2=t\implies x=\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{g}}\implies dx=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{g} \sqrt{t}}$$ All of that makes $$I=\frac{1}{2}g^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\int   t^{-\frac{k+1}{2}}e^{-t}\,dt=-\frac{1}{2}g^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{1-k}{2},t\right)$$ But for the definite integral, a requirement is $\Re(k)<1$.

Comment: I think the definition of $\Gamma$ function that you used in your answer says that $k$ should be smaller than some value (which I think in this particular case is $1$)

Comment: If we consider this then your answer is not right for general values of $k$. Please guide if  am wrong here. It is because of this constraint I asked this question here.

Comment: @FrankMoses. You are totally correct! I shall edit.